# How to get x-axis flags on dual axes chart with Highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How do you put flags on a Highchart with dual axes?

I've tried a bunch of things but I can't get it to render...

flags: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement

dual axes: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Comment: what have u tried??? put here some code or fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible http://jsfiddle.net/MGzjk/

```
 {
            type: 'flags',
            name: 'Flags on axis',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 2, 1),
                title: 'On axis'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2011, 3, 1),
                title: 'On axis'
            }],
            shape: 'squarepin'
        }
```

Comment: i think one huge point of confusion was that highstock implements highcharts. i didnt fully realize this until i included both libraries on my test page, and got an ERROR#16. this should be made cleared on the website.